# Router not working in angular2-rc1

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to use router in angular2. i have used one link to redirect to `DesignerComponent` and passing `page._id` as a `RouteParams`.
The code worked correctly in angular2-beta.
Below is my code:

**pages.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {SearchPipe} from './../../shared/pipes/search-pipe.pipe';
import { GlobalObjectsService} from './../../shared/services/global/global-objects.service';
import { Router,Routes , ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
import { DesignerComponent } from './../../+designer/designer.component';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-pages',
  pipes: [SearchPipe],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: 'pages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['pages.component.css']
})
@Routes([  
  {path: '/designer', component: DesignerComponent}
])
export class PagesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() pages:any;    
  constructor(private router:Router) {

  }
  ngOnInit() { }
  selectPage(page_id:string){                    
  }  

}
```

in my view, I have done Following:

```
<div [routerLink]="['Designer',{page_id: page._id}]" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Design Page">
    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i>
</div>
```

But its showing me below error:

```
Argument of type '{ path: string; name: string; component: typeof DesignerComponent; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteMetadata[]'
```

I just want to redirect to `DesignerComponent` on the click of link with page_id as an argument.

any inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add parameter in route metadata:

```
@Routes([  
  {path: '/designer/:page_id', component: DesignerComponent}
])
```

Use page._id in routerLink directly, without object:

```
[routerLink]="['/designer',page._id]"
```

**UPDATE**

accessing parameter value from component:

```
constructor(curr: RouteSegment) {
        let itemID = curr.getParam("page_id");
    }
```

Comment: but how can I access page._id in designer component as routeParams is not working?

Comment: I had typo in routerLink. instead of Designer should use /designer

Comment: that mean we have to use the same name `page_id` throughout everywhere i.e at the time of sending parameter and at the receiving end right ?

Answer (score 1):

The new `RouteDefinition` does not have a `name` property. So, just remove it like:

```
@Routes([  
  {path: '/designer', component: DesignerComponent}
])
```

The view will be:

<strike>`<div [routerLink]="['/designer',{page_id: page._id}]"  ... >`</strike>

```
<a [routerLink]="['/designer',{page_id: page._id}]"  ... >
```

Comment: Tried that.its showing error : `Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property`

Comment: any inputs on this?

Comment: Do you have a  <router-outlet> ? Sorry I am writing on my phone now. . Give me few minutes

Comment: it worked..but i needed to use `<a [routerLink]="['/designer',{page_id: page._id}]"</a>`  instead of  `<div [routerLink]="['/designer',{page_id: page._id}]"</div>` ..any reasons?

Comment: @BhushanGadekar that makes sense actually, because if you look at [the code of routerLink](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.1/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L5-L83). You can see that it has a binding to `href` attribute which is not available on div.